# Graphene symmetry breaking

Tags: symmetry, symmetry-breaking, electronic-band-theory, graphene

I was reading about the different symmetries that one could have in graphene.

Generally speaking, both the inversion symmetry of the honeycomb lattice and sublattice symmetry 'protect' the Dirac cones, and thus both need to be broken in order to open a band gap.

Can someone provide an intuitive explanation for how these symmetries breaking contribute to the opening of the band gap?

Comment: Could you give examples of how we can break one of these symmetries without breaking the other? Also, specify which *inversion symmetry* you mean - time inversion or one of the honeycomb lattice symmetries.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Roger, I edited my question. I hope it is clearer. What I specifically meant is the role of each symmetry in the pristine graphene and how the breaking of each 'perturbs' the system leading to the band gap.

Comment: Time reversal AND space inversion together protect the Dirac points. If you break any one of those symmetry you'll be able to open up a gap. If you write a $2\times 2$ Hamiltonian in like this $h(k) = \vec d(k) \cdot \vec \sigma$. Then time reversal symmetry implies $T h(k) T^{-1} = h(-k) \rightarrow h(k)^* = h(-k)$ and space inversion symmetry implies $\sigma_x h(k) \sigma_x  = h(-k)$. Hamiltonian has both symmetries, you'll be able to prove $d_3(k) = 0$, i.e. there is no mass term. So can't open a gap. If you'll break only one of the symmetry, then you can.

Comment: Thanks Galilean! Reading your comment, I see that the space inversion symmetry has the same implication as the chiral symmetry. This is true because the two sublattices actually formed by the same atoms (C), right?